# SVG Icon is not able to display in the application. Is there any solution for it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-material-icons

In one of my React Application, I am using Google Material Design Icons. As usual, there are icons and logos are not part of the Google Material Design Icons need to be added manually. In one of the case, I am trying to implement the **XING** Icon in my application, but it fails to display in the application.

**XING.js Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import pure from 'recompose/pure';
import {SvgIcon} from '@material-ui/core';

let xing = (props) => (
  <SvgIcon {...props} >
    <path d="M442.394 142c-1.736 0-3.197.61-3.934 1.803-.76 1.231-.645 2.818.166 4.424l19.503 33.761c.033.064.033.105 0 .164l-30.648 54.084c-.799 1.592-.76 3.191 0 4.425.736 1.187 2.033 1.966 3.771 1.966h28.844c4.312 0 6.393-2.91 7.867-5.57 0 0 29.973-53.01 31.14-55.068-.118-.19-19.83-34.58-19.83-34.58-1.439-2.557-3.606-5.41-8.03-5.41h-28.849z" fill="#005a5f"/><path d="M563.574 102.501c-4.309 0-6.176 2.714-7.723 5.494 0 0-62.14 110.2-64.188 113.818.105.196 40.984 75.191 40.984 75.191 1.432 2.558 3.641 5.494 8.06 5.494h28.81c1.738 0 3.096-.654 3.828-1.843.77-1.23.748-2.857-.059-4.458l-40.664-74.295a.167.167 0 0 1 0-.189l63.863-112.92c.803-1.594.82-3.22.061-4.452-.736-1.188-2.098-1.843-3.836-1.843h-29.139v.002h.003z" fill="#d4d600"/>
  </SvgIcon>
);

xing = pure(xing);
xing.displayName = 'xing';     
xing.muiName = 'SvgIcon';

export default xing;
```

**footer.js**

Here I am trying to use the Google Matiral Design Icons as well as **XING** Icon:

```
import React from "react";
import { Facebook, YouTube } from '@material-ui/icons';
import Xing from '../footer/Xing';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

...
...

 const socialMedia = (
        <div class="has-text-centered">
          <section class="hero">
          <div class="hero-body">
            <div class="container">          
              <h1 class="title">{L10n.format("social_media")}</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
            <br/>
            </section>
          <div class="social-media-margin">
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
              <span className="social-media-icon">              
              <a
                href={"https://www.youtube.com/"}
                target="_blank" 
              ><YouTube /></a>             
            </span>
            </div>
          
            <div class="column">
              <span className="social-media-icon">              
              <a                
                href={"https://www.facebook.com/"}
                target="_blank"
              ><Facebook/></a>
              </span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="column">              
              <span className="social-media-icon">              
              <a                
                href={"https://www.xing.com/"}
                target="_blank"
              ><Xing/>          
              </a>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
  );

  return (
    <footer className="footer">
      {bannerAddition}
      {socialMedia}      
      <div className="columns is-centered footer-colmns">
        {products}
        {solutions}
        {service}
        {company}
      </div>
      
      {legalInformation}      
    </footer>
  );
};

export default footer;
```

***SVG DATA of XING**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2128" height="2500" viewBox="426.896 102.499 170.207 200">
  <path d="M442.394 142c-1.736 0-3.197.61-3.934 1.803-.76 1.231-.645 2.818.166 4.424l19.503 33.761c.033.064.033.105 0 .164l-30.648 54.084c-.799 1.592-.76 3.191 0 4.425.736 1.187 2.033 1.966 3.771 1.966h28.844c4.312 0 6.393-2.91 7.867-5.57 0 0 29.973-53.01 31.14-55.068-.118-.19-19.83-34.58-19.83-34.58-1.439-2.557-3.606-5.41-8.03-5.41h-28.849z" fill="#005a5f"/>
  <path d="M563.574 102.501c-4.309 0-6.176 2.714-7.723 5.494 0 0-62.14 110.2-64.188 113.818.105.196 40.984 75.191 40.984 75.191 1.432 2.558 3.641 5.494 8.06 5.494h28.81c1.738 0 3.096-.654 3.828-1.843.77-1.23.748-2.857-.059-4.458l-40.664-74.295a.167.167 0 0 1 0-.189l63.863-112.92c.803-1.594.82-3.22.061-4.452-.736-1.188-2.098-1.843-3.836-1.843h-29.139v.002h.003z" fill="#d4d600"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

two issues:

React component must start with Capital letter. So not xing, but Xing.

Apart from that everything is fine, except that you path in svg seems to be corrupted. It does not work regardless whether it's wrapped in component or just directly outlined as svg element. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-paper-7nbxr?file=/src/App.js

Where did you get that path from?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I downloaded XING Logo from their website and then opened it with VS Code. In VS Code, I could see the path of SVG file.

Comment: Please check your path string if you copied it fully. I just copied the svg path string to my codesandbox linked above, and it showed the logo. This string was much longer that what you have.

Comment: thanks again, unfortunately no success with two different SVG paths. 

I am trying to make it small with this link:

https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to style the svg ? Like put a height or width on it in the inspector to see ? Or maybe just inspect it to see what height and width it has.

I don't know about Xing but most of the time, there's no width applied to these and you have to specify it in your css (like with FontAwesome)